# How to pass argument when extend Robotframework AppiumLibrary to call appium execute_script function

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, appium-android, python-appium

I have create a python file with the following content

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def scroll_page_to_the_bottom():
    BuiltIn().get_library_instance('AppiumLibrary').execute_script("mobile: scroll", {'direction': 'down'})
```

When I call from robot file with keyword `scroll_page_to_the_bottom` I got an error `TypeError: too many positional arguments`

I thought something wrong with my scripts and I try to use other mobile command such as `mobile: deviceInfo` and it works perfectly
Here is the working execute_script from my code `BuiltIn().get_library_instance('AppiumLibrary').execute_script("mobile: deviceInfo")`

My question is how to pass command with argument to `execute_script`?

referring to http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/index.html, I have use the correct format `execute_script("mobile: scroll", {'direction': 'down'})` but got an error `TypeError: too many positional arguments` from robot execution

Comment: Please show the complete, actual error.

Comment: @BryanOakley this is the error TypeError: too many positional arguments

Answer (score 0):

Your python code is calling the `execute_script()` method on a `AppiumLibrary` object, from the [robotframework-appiumlibrary](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary) package. This method receives only one parameter (`script`), and you are passing two arguments: 1. the string `"mobile: scroll"` and 2. the dict `{'direction': 'down'}`. Hence the `TypeError: too many positional arguments` exception.

The second example you gave works because you passed the correct number of arguments: the string `"mobile: deviceInfo"`.

The page http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/index.html documents the `execute_script()` method from the [appium-python-client](https://github.com/appium/python-client) package, and this is a different package. The method you are calling is not there.